# Optional depencency on target in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to create an optional dependency on a target in Makefile (GNU Make)?

```
help:
    @echo Usage:

clean:
    @echo Cleaning...

build: clean?
    @echo Building...
```

The expected output:

```sh
$ make
Usage:

$ make clean
Cleaning...

$ make build
Building...

$ make build clean
Cleaning...
Building...

$ make clean build
Cleaning...
Building...
```

The set of targets **is fixed** and **can not be extended**, i.e.

```
rebuild: clean build

.PHONY: rebuild
```

is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
build: $(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
        @echo Building...
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html
and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter